# My Car, She Was Driving, Who Pays the Lapsed Registration Ticket?

Tags: ethics

The title sums the situation up pretty well.

My friend was out driving in my car (with my permission) when the car received a ticket (while parked--she wasn't in the car) for a lapsed registration.

Ethically speaking, is that her ticket to pay or mine?

Comment: In this case the ticket was for the lapsed registration, which was continuously lapsed since the moment it lapsed, not for "parking with lapsed registration". On the other hand, if there was a fine for "driving with lapsed registration" on top of that, and she knew about the lapsed registration, she should pay.

Comment: It's a registration issue, it's on the owner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To whom was the information necessary to avoid the ticket provided?  You.  So there is your answer.

Responsibility presumes power, she had no power over whether or not to register your car.  For her to do so would not have been legal.

It was irresponsible for you to give her permission to break the law.

Comment: Legal? (character count)